# Graph Api File Upload to Sharepoint Library Json Format Error

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps

I'm trying to upload a simple txt document to a sharepoint library, from power apps, using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3mhe88BI34&ab_channel=RezaDorrani).

I think I'm doing it right, troubleshooted a lot of permissions issues trough the process, but I got stuck in this error:

```
Unabel to read JSON request payload.
```

I'm just sending a put request using this:

```
Office365Groups.HttpRequest(
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{mySiteId}/drives/{myDriveId}/root:/file.txt:/content:",
        "PUT",
        ThisRecord.Value
    )
```

`mySiteIdid` and `myDriveId`, I got them both correct. `ThisRecord.Value` is the file content from the attachment field.

I also get the same result if I try this on the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

It clearly states in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell), that the payload should be text/plain.

- Why would it ask for a json content-type if the documentation states
  for a text/plain payload?
- Any clues on how to move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you remove `:` of the url

```
/v1.0/sites/{mySiteId}/drives/{myDriveId}/root:/file.txt:/content:
/v1.0/sites/{mySiteId}/drives/{myDriveId}/root:/file.txt:/content
```

I would also set the `Content-Type` parameter to `text/plain`

```
Office365Groups.HttpRequest(
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{mySiteId}/drives/{myDriveId}/root:/file.txt:/content",
    "PUT",
    ThisRecord.Value,
    "text/plain"
)
```

[Office 365 group - send HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groups/#send-an-http-request)